# advice on UIViewController hierarchy and flow

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I'm spending a lot time reading apple View Controller Programming but still can't get a clue of how to code for my flow.

I'm using ViewController, PageViewController, and Storyboard.

My **rootViewController** is a ViewController
I want two more ViewController

- first, **PageViewController** to show pages of tutorials and last page has signup with presentViewController login
- **secondViewController**, ViewController is the main content of the app

if case user has token in keychain will go to **secondViewController**.
After signup or login lead to **secondViewController**.

I didn't use navigation controller. Wonder this can be done by container view controller?

current problem In signupViewController self.parentViewController is **pageViewController** but I can't get the **rootViewController**, to dismiss and add secondViewController

P/S but In loginViewController self.presentingViewController I got the rootViewController!! it is out of my expectation.. I wonder why???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Set secondViewController as your rootViewController of UIWindow in AppDelegate. SecondViewController contains the base view content without data about login, so you can launch as soon as you can.
2. If user has token in keychain, just to update SecondViewController view with login status.
3. If user has no token in keychain, show PageViewController on SecondViewController, with presenting a viewController or just addSubview. After PageViewController, present loginViewController, when login finish, dismiss the loginViewController, update SecondViewController view  with login status which is same with step2

Comment: pageViewController last page is signup. The problem is I cannot get the rootViewController or dismiss to the rootViewController after signup. pageViewController show the SignupViewController are not present or add subview. it is by delegate protocol to return the ViewController to pageViewController

Comment: in loginViewController, just do `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]`

Answer (score 0):

You use storyboard, so I assume you'll also use segue. Your PageViewController can be the entry point, with a segue to secondViewController.

If you have the token in the keychain, you can programatically perform the segue using:

`[self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"MySegue" sender: self];`

Otherwise users stay on PageViewController to serve its original flow.

Comment: I created segue from PageViewController to secondViewController, but I'm not able to get my pageViewController from SignupViewController. hence i can't do [self.parentViewController performSegueWithIndentifier:@"mySegue" sender:self] after user touch button too

Comment: Will you change the direction? i.e. the secondViewController as entry point. If there's no token in the keychain, modal the page view controller and the pages and use unwind segue after you have successfully sign-up?

Comment: no, always rootViewController to pageView to secondView, or rootViewController to secondView only